# jQuery get cannot bring me a non-string variable

Tags: jquery

here is my code

```
jQuery.get('http://example.com/text.txt', function(data) {
    var newDate = new Date(data);
    /*
    ....
    */
});
```

My text.txt contains a date with this format : 2015,5,28,20,10 (Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute). The thing is that I want this :

```
var newDate = new Date(2015,5,28,20,10);
```

But data  is actually a string. So, I guess that I get this :

```
var newDate = new Date("2015,5,28,20,10");
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what does the console say? `console.log(data);`? are there any errors?

Comment: Console says : 2015,5,28,20,10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `.split()` , `.map()` , `.apply()`

```js
var data = "2015,5,28,20,10".split(/,/).map(function(n) {
             return Number(n)
           });

var newDate = new Date(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);

document.write(newDate);
```

Comment: Thanks. Just after Cory's answer, i used : 

`var array = data.split(",");
  for( num in array){
   num = Number(num);
  }
  var newDate = new Date(array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4]);`

Answer (score 1):

** UPDATE - this is not working ** accept guest271314's answer

This is not ideal, as your data text has to be right format (though you could write in some error handling). You have to get that date string to numbers in order for the date() to work. So, remove the commas from the string, then convert the string to a number. Like this:

```
     //here is your string from the txt file
 var string = "2015,5,28,20,10" 
  //remove the commas
 var nums = string.replace(/,/g , "");
  //convert the string to a number
 nums = Number(nums)
  //get the date
 var newDate = new Date(nums);
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/32q2p656/

Comment: wait, this is wrong, sorry. take guest271314's answer